# Difficulties initializing an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following code:

```
print Dumper($dec_res->{repositories}[0]);
print Dumper($dec_res->{repositories}[1]);


my @repos = ($dec_res->{repositories});
print scalar @repos . "\n";
```

and the output is the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'status' => 'OK',
          'name' => 'apir',
          'svnUrl' => 'https://url.whatever/svn/apir',
          'id' => 39,
          'viewvcUrl' => 'https://url.whatever/viewvc/apir/'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'status' => 'OK',
          'name' => 'CCDS',
          'svnUrl' => 'https://url.whatever/svn/CCDS',
          'id' => 26,
          'viewvcUrl' => 'https://url.whatever/viewvc/CCDS/'
        };

1
```

So my question is why `$dec_res->{repositories}` is clearly an array but `@repos` is not?

Here I printed the size but even trying to access elements with `$repos[0]` still returns an error.

Dumping `$repos[0]` actually print the whole structure... like dumping `$dec_res->{repositories}`

Comment: There is [no such thing as PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `$dec_res->{repositories}` is clearly an array

It isn't. It is an *array reference*.

> but `@repos` is not?

It is an array.

You are creating a list that is one item long, and that item is the array reference. You then assign the list to the array, so the array holds that single item.

You need to dereference the array instead.

```
my @repos = @{$dec_res->{repositories}};
```

[perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) explains more about references in Perl.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that this was an array $dec_res->{repositories} because $dec_res->{repositories}[0] actually returned the first element of the array